# Étale homotopy type of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_\infty \}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, etale-covers

Has anyone formally calculated the étale homotopy type of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}$?

According to arithmetic topology, $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}$ is formally analogous to $S^3$, so I predict that this is the étale homotopy type. We should have $\pi_3(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_2(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}) \cong 0$, and $\pi_1(\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}) = 0$.

Comment: And $\pi_1=0$ ?

Comment: Ok,. Try this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/186140/4177

Comment: Shoot, I intended to compactify.

Comment: shall we close this as duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the higher homotopy groups of Spec Z ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3103/what-are-the-higher-homotopy-groups-of-spec-z)

Comment: @DavidRoberts I intended to compactify it first; I hope you don't mind if I change it to $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \cup \{ \text{place}_{\infty} \}$.

Comment: no probs, that would make it a different question :-)

Comment: What is your definition of etale homotopy type after adding the infinite place?

Comment: What topos corresponds to $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\cup\{\infty\}$? I know of a couple of proposals, but they're both in a rather embrional stage...

Comment: This question has already 5 upvotes but still doesn't make sense. Please clarify what you mean by $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{Z} \cup \{{\rm place}_\infty\}$ or its etale homotopy type.

Comment: I like to think in terms of the pro-smooth topos (filtered limits of smooth maps). This might not have a candidate for a weakly contractible cover, though (I haven’t found one). Certainly the ordinary smooth topos does not. I respect your concern for a grounded question. But it seems from what @DenisNardin is saying that in choosing the topos, I might only get one or a few of the proposals and a limited perspective. I would much rather hear a broad answer overviewing the current state of the literature than limit myself to a partial view by committing myself to a particular topos.

Comment: @DeanYoung Can you give a pointer to where the pro-smooth topos of $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$ is defined? I have no idea of what you're referring to. Note that $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$ is not a scheme, so the general definitions do not apply.

Comment: I'm okay with a broad scope, I was more concerned with the set of possible precise formulations of your question being empty.

Comment: how many connected components does your thing have?